# Validating a form in Twitter Bootstrap Model

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a form in a modal with some required fields, but when I hit submit the form just reloads and I don't get any message for validation that I am using for submitting the form jQuery, as below :

```
<script>
    $('#InfroTextSubmit').click(function(){
        $('#InfroText').submit();
    });
</script>
```

The Twitter Bootstrap Modal Code is :

```
<!-- Modal1 -->
<div id="myModal1" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
    <h3 id="myModalLabel">Edit Introduction</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <form id="InfroText" method="POST">
      <input type="hidden" name="InfroText" value="1"/>
      <table>
        <tr><td>Title</td><td><input type="text" name="title" style="width:300px" required="require"/></td></tr>
        <tr><td>Introudction</td><td><textarea name="contect" style="width:300px;height:200px"></textarea></td></tr>
      </table>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" id="InfroTextSubmit">Save changes</button>
  </div>
</div>
<script>
    $('#InfroTextSubmit').click(function(){
        $('#InfroText').submit();
    });
</script>
```

So how can i Validate the Form and not let the model close and reload if something is wrong with the form ?

Regards,

Answer (score 8):

You don't have to add any script for validating form text fields if you added the required attribute.

Try this

`<input type="text" name="title" style="width:300px" required="required"/>`

or

`<input type="text" name="title" style="width:300px" required/>`

Comment: I tried this required="require" for the input type='text' above but it is closing the model .

Comment: Try `required="required"` or the second one I provided.

Comment: Where is it documented? It doesn't work in Bootstrap 3+. Has it been removed? All I see is a manual way to add 'has-error' class.

Comment: In bootstrap, as I know you have to add `data-rule-required="true"` to your input. So if you don't enter value and submit, it will add a label to end of input with message as "This field is required.". class "has-error" is added to display it as red. 
`required="required"` is from HTML only. So if you don't use bootstrap and mentioned as `required="required"` it will show message to fill the field. No need of bootstrap there :)

Answer (score 3):

You can add `"data-dismiss=modal"` to the InfroTextSubmit button, and then use 'return false' on the '`#InfroTextSubmit`' click function to prevent the form from closing. If the form is valid you call 'submit()'.

**Button code:**

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true" id="save">Save changes</button>
```

**Click function:**

```
$('#save').click(function(){

    if ($('#myField1').val()==="") {
      // invalid
      $('#myField1').next('.help-inline').show();
      return false;
    }
    else {
      // submit the form here
      $('#InfroText').submit();
      return true;
    }     
});
```

There a several different approaches to the validation itself.

**Working on Bootply**: http://bootply.com/60244