# Validation in a Twitter Bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

This is the duplicate of [Validating a form in Twitter Bootstrap Model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16273641/validating-a-form-in-twitter-bootstrap-model/22440417#22440417)

However, my question is If i launch modal and click on save changes it shows required field. Once i close the modal and launch still the "field is required" is showing..I want the "field is required" to close once the modal is closed..

You can see the demo here http://www.bootply.com/60244

Answer (score 0):

If you want a quick way to solve that, you can hide the "field is required" when you open the modal again.

```
$('#myModal1').click(function(){
      $('#title').next('.help-inline').hide();   
});
```

Comment: Have you checked if the id I placed on the first line (click) is correct?